# ion-toggle doesn't call ng-change function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am switching ion-toggle as shown below. It is calling `vatt()` function, when I click the toggle's switch button. But when I change it using another button, it is switching toggle's side, but it does not call `validate()` function. How can I solve this problem?

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="p.checked"
    ng-change="vatt()"
    class="item item-text-wrap">
   My Toggle
</ion-toggle>

<button class="button button-positive" ng-click="check()">Tikla</button>
```

My controller script has this code.

```
$scope.p = {id: 1, text: 'USA', checked: false, icon: null};
$scope.check = function () {
   $scope.p.checked = false;
   console.log("asdad");
}
$scope.vatt = function () {
    console.log("GORRRRR");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior of the `ng-change` function. It is just called when the component is changed. Not from another function.

But you can do something like this in the controller.

```
$scope.check = function () {
   $scope.p.checked = false;
   console.log("asdad");
   $scope.vatt();
}
$scope.vatt = function () {
    console.log("GORRRRR");
}
```